# Example of an integrable function with non integrable square

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a measure space, how can I find an example of a function $f$ such that $f \in L(X)$ - the space of real valued Lebesgue integrable functions, but $f^2 \notin L(X)$. I know this example can't be a series (with the counting measure), or an integral in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue Measure - because in both cases, integrability means that $f$ tends to zero on infinity, which means that the square decreases faster, and it follows that the square of $f$ is integrable.
Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Hint: power rule on $(0,1)$.

Comment: what do you mean by 'power rule'?

Comment: integration using the power rule

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^a$ and determine $a$ so that $f\in L^1((0,1))$ but $f\not\in L^2((0,1)).$

Comment: Tried $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$, seems to have worked. Thanks!